# getStringExtra - Public Static Final - The Busy Coder's Guide to Android

Tags: android

I am on page 301 of this book and it is an example of an Activity getting "extras" from the intent that started it. I am fairly new to Java so maybe am missing something pretty obvious but... 
I thought that when you declare a variable as "final" it meant that it doesn't change.

There is a line of code initialising a final variable:

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="msg";

and then later in onCreate method:

tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE));

The text displayed in the activity is not "msg" but is the string passed from the intent "I am the other activity". Why do you have to have the variable declaration above for the code to work? I don't understand what its doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the `extra` received from another `Activity` indexed by the **key** 'msg'.

Like when you do this with the `Intent` used to start your `Activity`:

```
intent.putExtra("msg", "text going in the TextView");
```

The key is 'msg', but the value you get for the `TextView` is 'text going in the TextView'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `final` means `EXTRA_MESSAGE` value won't change, but you're not displaying `EXTRA_MESSAGE` value, but

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)
```

which actually contains the value put in the previous activity. Regarding your question

*Why do you have to have the variable declaration above for the code to work?*

You don't actually *need* that variable for the code to work, but it's a good practice to use constant values instead of just hardcoding string values such in.-

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("msg")
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you pass to getStringExtra is the key to which the String is mapped. All the extras you put in an Intent are mapped as key-value, so if you want to get a value you have to know the key, which must be the same key you used in the previous activity to save the value (with putStringExtra).

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29)